# Получить отфильтрованный Vue.js + axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

с апи ранее не работал. Мне нужно отобразить объекты массива, поле type которых будет равно "FILTER". Иначе - не отображать.
API моего ответа:

```js
"itemsdata": [{
    "name": "TEST",
    "type": "FILTER",
  },
  {
    "name": "TEST2",
    "type": "NOFILTER"
  }
]
```

Как правильнее будет это сделать?

Пробовал просто в консоли для начала выводить следующее: `console.log(response.data.itemsdata[0].type);` Данные отображаются.
  Но в таком случае `console.log(response.data.itemsdata.type);` - консоль выводит undefined. Тогда как мне обращаться сразу ко всем моим объектам, без индекса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, вопрос мало имеет отношения к `API`, `Axios` и `VueJS`, но попробуй что-то вроде:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "TEST",
    "type": "FILTER",
  },
  {
    "name": "TEST2",
    "type": "NOFILTER"
  }
]

if (typeof data === 'object' && data.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].type === 'FILTER') {
      console.log(data[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: да, я уже понял. Думал, синтаксически все должно выглядеть иначе. Ошибался. Зеленый еще, много вопросов возникает потому.
Проблему уже разрешил, но ваш ответ отмечу полезным. Благодарю! Чуть позже выпишу сюда и свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

```js
const response = { data: { itemsdata: [
  { "name": "TEST", "type": "FILTER" },
  { "name": "TEST2", "type": "NOFILTER" }, 
  { "name": "TEST3", "type": "FILTER" }
]}}; 

const filtered = response.data.itemsdata.filter(o => o.type === 'FILTER'); 
console.log(filtered);
```